# url should rewrite if page and query string is match

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect page if my url and query string is matched i have try much but no success, can you please told me where i done mistake.

My url is

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/search/videos?search_query=xxx+xxx
```

and I want to redirect (rewrite using .htaccess) it to

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/search/videos/xxx+xxx
```

I have tryed

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^search/videos$ search/videos/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "search_query=" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search/videos/$1? [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search/videos/$1? [L,QSA]
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i want rewrite `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/search/videos?search_query=xxx+xxx` this url to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/search/videos/xxx+xxx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
#terminate the 2nd rewrite iteration
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# redirect "/search/videos?search_query?foobar" to "/search/videos/foobar"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^search/videos$ /search/videos/%1? [R=301,L]
#internally map "/search/videos/foobar" to "/search/videos?search_query?foobar" 
RewriteRule ^search/videos/([^/]+)/?$ /search/videos/?search_query=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: not working... still i am on same url. can i need to consider query string value also when writing rewrite rule? `xxx+xxx` i mean this plus sign also i need to add in regex?

Comment: Not working. did you think this problem is related to `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes` MultiViews? because "search/videos?search_query=xxx+xxx" in this search is a "search.php".

Comment: Hey bro thanks, this problem is related to +MultiViews. if you have enabled +MultiViews you can not use rewrite rule if file is exist in root. my search.php was on root so .htaccess not taking any rewrite rule for search. i have just removed that.